# Android: How to create empty realm object?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

I tried to create an empty realm object by following code:

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
var arr = ArrayList<SildayAlarm>()
val myModel: MyModel? = realm.createObject(MyModel::class.java)
```

MyModel.kt

```
@RealmClass
open class MyModel(
    var code: Int? = 0
): RealmObject()
```

But I got the error like this :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot modify managed objects outside
>   of a write transaction. in
>   /Users/cm/Realm/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsObject.cpp
>   line 336

Comment: Can you please share bit more lines of code and error log?

Comment: I don't have much code yet cuz I just need to create an empty Object that is a RealmObject class. Look at my new update

Comment: let us know if you got solution.

Comment: You are missing `realm.executeTransaction {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create object with realm instance will perform transaction on realm Database.

So you should have to wrap that code inside transaction wrapper.

**1)**

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
realm.beginTransaction();   // To start realm transaction.
val myModel: MyModel? = realm.createObject(MyModel::class.java) // Create a new object
realm.commitTransaction();   // To complete realm transaction.
```

Or use realm's transaction method.

**2)**

```
val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
      val myModel: MyModel? = realm.createObject(MyModel::class.java) // Create a new object
}
```

**Note:**

All write operations on this newly created realm Object should perform under those realm transaction block.